# IdentityServer 4 with Multiple Bindings

Tags: single-sign-on, identityserver4

I have 2 sites (www.dogsite.com and www.catsite.com). They are pointed to login.identityserverdemo.com as my authority server. This allows the SSO to work between the two sites. Now if I add two more bindings to my login.identityserverdemo.com site called login.dogsite.com and login.catsite.com, I will lose the SSO. I have tried adding the www.dogsite.com and www.catsite.com to the client's redirectUrls with no improvement.

Here is my client config:

```
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "mvc-dog",
                ClientName = "MVC Client For Dog Site",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                RequireConsent = false,
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("woofwoof123".Sha256())
                },
                Claims = new List<Claim>
                { },

                RedirectUris           = { "http://www.catsite.com/signin-oidc", "http://www.dogsite.com/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://www.catsite.com/signout-callback-oidc","http://www.dogsite.com/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "api1"
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true
            },
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "mvc-cat",
                ClientName = "MVC Client For Cat Site",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                RequireConsent = false,
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("MeowMeow456".Sha256())
                },

                Claims = new List<Claim>
                {},

                RedirectUris           = { "http://www.catsite.com/signin-oidc", "http://www.dogsite.com/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://www.catsite.com/signout-callback-oidc","http://www.dogsite.com/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "api1"
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true
            }
```

Please help??

Answer (score 0):

You lose SSO because login.dogsite.com and login.catsite.com cannot get access to the same idSrv cookies.

Check out [Cross domain cookie option](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/3438). It's for ID3 but is equally applicable to ID4.